# Why google map doen't show cafe, restaurents in suggested areas

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Google map in my application it shows places in it's suggested area and if i click it, it shows route as my expectation but it never show me any cafe in it's suggestions.
So my question is that, how i get that kind of suggestions from map?
is there any library for that?

Comment: Post what you implemented till now.

Comment: @Codelord i implemented normal app which shows route between me and my destination address. but if i want to use my destination as cafe, restaurant. it never shows me that kind of places in it's suggestion list.
That's why i never able to enter my destination place.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Google Places API
https://developers.google.com/places/?csw=1

A short tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/
OR
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup--mobile-15771

Comment: i used same concept to do that, but it only shows area, not sub-area of that area or cafes.

Comment: Silly question, have you activated places API from google developer console?

Comment: I have updated my response with a link to a tutorial.